# Creating a template in Tableau to make moving between similar excel files smooth

Tags: excel, tableau-api

I am very new to Tableau and just finished my first sheet/dashboard combination for a set of data.

I now want to be able to open up various other excel workbooks (similarly named headers/sheets etc) and get the same Tableau dashboard (with calculated fields etc) just with the new data.

I can open each workbook one by one and switch data sources between each, but is there a simpler way? Also this doesnt maintain calculated fields which is a necessity!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bernardo's solution of duplicating the data source works fine, but you end up with multiple copies of your data source - one per data file. That gets hard to manage, and if you revise a calculated field, you have to remember to change it in each data source.

An alternative is to double click on the data source name to edit it, and then click on the orange pathname to the Excel file in the top left of the data connection pane. Select the file you wish.

This approach leaves everything unchanged, simply points Tableau at a different Excel file. If both files share the same structure, and you aren't trying to show file A values side by side with file B values, then its probably your simplest approach

Comment: Hi Alex, I'm not seeing an orange pathname when I try to do this. Where are you clicking on the data source name? In a worksheet? In the Data Source tab? Thanks!

Comment: top left part of the Data Source tab

Answer (score 1):

Open your tableau workbook and duplicate the data source by right clicking on the name. Then edit the new data source in the data window and choose your next Excel file. It will keep your calc fields.

[image: duplicate]

Then if you want your old worksheets to point to the new data source, right click on your data source and select Replace Data Source